# SQL error when i want comparate values of two query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The idea is that I would like to gather several table values ​​in a column named "entrcod", and then have them compared to another query I am trying in my join query.

AND if a value exists in the first request and in the second it sends me the duplicate

CODE WITHOUT ERROR BUT DONT HAVE ALL VALUES I WANT

```
         SELECT entrcod FROM marchelot WHERE marcod = 494128
         AND entrcod IN
         
         (SELECT entrcod FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT betcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT buccod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT ouvrcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT oeuvcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001')
```

CODE WITH INFORMATION I WANT , BUT WITH ERROR

```
         SELECT entrcod FROM marchelot WHERE marcod = 494128
           UNION
             select buccod as entrcod from marchebuc where marcod = 494128 
            UNION
             select ouvrcod as entrcod from marcheouvrage where marcod = 494128 
           UNION
           select oeuvcod as entrcod  from marcheoeuvre where marcod = 494128          
          
         AND entrcod IN
         
         (SELECT entrcod FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT betcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT buccod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT ouvrcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT oeuvcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001')
```

THE ERROR

MySQL a répondu : Documentation

#1054 - Champ 'entrcod' inconnu dans IN/ALL/ANY subquery

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form. Also, if this question is **really** related to PHP, share the PHP code

Comment: I join a Screen of my error in PhpMyAdmin :) thx

Comment: Please do not share text as a link to an image. Copy the text itself into your question.

Comment: I edit the post with the error Text ,thx

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Sounds like there's a column missing? Also, how is this this related to PHP itself?

Comment: I tried to put my 2 SQL queries in two different variables and do an array_intersect to compare the two arrays, but that doesn't work either...

so I'm trying to do it directly in SQL ,

in two different requests it gives me the right information

Comment: In the end I just want to make a comparison of my tables, to output a duplicate present in the 2 tables.

If a duplicate exists, I would do something with the variable like:
"
IF (!empty($test_1)){do something}

Comment: If this is a pure SQL problem, please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is misleading

Your query must look like this to work

your condition for  `entrcod IN` doesn't exist in your query, adding an alias to the original query fixes that

```
SELECT entrcod FROM
           
    (SELECT entrcod FROM marchelot WHERE marcod = 494128
           UNION
             select buccod as entrcod from marchebuc where marcod = 494128 
            UNION
             select ouvrcod as entrcod from marcheouvrage where marcod = 494128 
           UNION
           select oeuvcod as entrcod  from marcheoeuvre where marcod = 494128          
          ) t1
         WHERE entrcod IN
         
         (SELECT entrcod FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT betcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
          SELECT buccod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT ouvrcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
          
          UNION
          
           SELECT oeuvcod
          FROM prospectuserclient
          WHERE procod = 20347 AND usercod = '001'
)
```

| entrcod |
| --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MgDAnSIj)

Comment: It's work really well , i finally see my mistake,thx  !